# How to suggest new friends in Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin

I have an orientdb graph database setup with User as vertex and Friend as edge.

2 Users are friends if they have 2 edges with each other:

u1 --Friend --> u2  and u2 -- Friend --> u1

How can I suggest friends of friends to u1 with Gremlin and make sure those people are not current friends of u1, with a single chain of Gremlin functions?

Here's my Gremlin code so far, but I want to filter out vertices already friends with u1:

`u1.out('Friend').out('Friend').dedup()`

I tried this but doesn't seem to work:

`u1.out('Friend').out('Friend').dedup().filter{ it!= u1.out('Friend')}`

Thank you for your help :).

Comment: With your approach you would need to do something like `u1.out('friend').out('friend').dedup.filter{ !u1.out('friend').toList().contains(it) && it != u1}` which is of course highly inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose that you also sort the recommendations by some property, e.g. the number of paths of length 2 from the start user to the recommended user and hence apply basic collaborative filtering as proposed on the [gremlin github home page](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki).

Applied to your problem we could write:

```
m = [:]; known = [u1]; u1.out('friend').aggregate(known).out('friend').except(known).groupCount(m)
m = m.sort{-it.value}
```

This gives you a map `m` ordered descending by the values which are the number of distinct paths of length 2 and the vertices of the users recommended as friends to user `u1` as keys.

Hereafter an example:

```
g = new TinkerGraph()
u1 = g.addVertex('u1')
u2 = g.addVertex('u2')
u3 = g.addVertex('u3')
u4 = g.addVertex('u4')
u5 = g.addVertex('u5')

g.addEdge(u1,u2,'friend')
g.addEdge(u2,u1,'friend')
g.addEdge(u2,u3,'friend')
g.addEdge(u3,u2,'friend')
g.addEdge(u1,u5,'friend')
g.addEdge(u5,u1,'friend')
g.addEdge(u5,u4,'friend')
g.addEdge(u4,u5,'friend')
g.addEdge(u2,u4,'friend')
g.addEdge(u4,u2,'friend')
g.addEdge(u5,u2,'friend')
g.addEdge(u2,u5,'friend')
```

The content of the map after the proposed query for user `u1` is:

```
gremlin> m
==>v[u4]=2
==>v[u3]=1
```

Maybe you also need to think about the impact on the query result of directed friendship edges without the corresponding edge in the opposite direction …